# Highlight rows where the data column is a Mon, Wed, Fri, or Su

Tags: excel, format, formula

For readability, we would like to highlight *the entire row*, if the first column is a Monday, Wednesday, Friday, or Sunday. That is, we want to highlight *the entire row* if its date column contains one of every second day of the week.

```
Monday**********
Monday**********
Monday**********
Monday**********
Monday**********
Tuesday
Tuesday
Wednesday**********
Wednesday**********
Wednesday**********
Thursday
Friday**********
Friday**********
Friday**********
Saturday
Saturday
Sunday**********
Sunday**********
Monday**********
Monday**********
Monday**********
Monday**********
Tuesday
Tuesday
Wednesday**********
Wednesday**********
Wednesday**
Thursday
Friday**********
Friday**********
Friday**********
Friday**********
Saturday
Saturday
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what we ended up doing:

## Answer

1. Home Tab > Styles > Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules
2. New Rule
3. Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
4. Enter `=MOD(WEEKDAY($A1),2)=0`, where column `A` contains our date values.
5. Format > Fill > Some Colour.

## Explanation

- `WEEKDAY(date)` returns a number between one and seven.
- `MOD(numerator, denominator)` finds the remainder after dividing.
- If the remainder is zero, then it's an even day of the week.
- The `$` before `A1` kind of says: "Apply this to the entire row."

## Screenshots

[image: Conditional Formatting]

[image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager]

[image: Edit Formatting Rule]